# how can path of storage image be taken?

Tags: image, storage, codenameone

I have an image named abc.png in storage, how can get the full path of the image in code name one? I am able to get image path using getHOmepath in filesystemstorage but unable to get path from the storage image.

Answer (score 0):

`Storage` doesn't have paths. In order to get a path to the file you will need to copy it to the `FileSystemStorage`. The logic here is that some OS's don't expose the data we map to `Storage` in the same way e.g. in RIM/J2ME Storage is mapped to `RMS` which isn't a filesytem at all.

Comment: As there is no FileSystemStorage in iphone/ ipad , How can we get the path of the file in iphone / ipad ?

Comment: I don't know where you got that from. The FileSystemStorage works just fine on iOS. It behaves a bit differently but works.

Comment: can you give simple example for this

Comment: Of what? Using the FileSystemStorage? All existing examples of FileSystemStorage from the developer guide/demos should work fine on iOS.